# How to select the particular row data in jsp using radio button

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I know its a basic question and please bear with this.

I'm new to struts frame work and I'm creating a sample application using struts 1.2. I've inserted few values into the database using form beans. And i'm displaying all the database records in the jsp page using  function. and i also placed the radio button for each row..

Now my question is, i want to select a particular data from the records displayed in the jsp page by clicking the radio button and i need to store the selected records into the another table.

Give me some suggestion regarding the condition specified above...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to store the id/unique value of that row in radio button value, and send it to your action class to do save the values in another table.

Comment: i specified like this now how to set id for the each row sorry if asking basic questions <nested:iterate property="viewobj">
     
     <tr>      
      <td ><nested:write property="accno" /></td>
            
      <td ><nested:write property="name" /></td>
            
<td ><nested:write property="gender" /></td>
           
      <td><nested:write property="amount" /></td>
           
      <td><nested:write property="address" /></td>
      
<td><input type="radio"/></td>
</tr>                                        
</nested:iterate>

Comment: Set some values in your radio button like `<input type="radio" value="<nested:write property="accno" />"/>`. By the way you will get some value from your radio. Once you check and choose the button to save you get the value from radio and do your stuff.

Comment: You are welcome. Find my detailed answer below to get more information. That may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you set those unique values in radio button, you can get the values for your purpose. Like using jquery,

```
var selRadio = $('input:radio[name=cname]:checked').val();
```

You can find out [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnbSf/) explains how to get checked value.

Use some ajax for send that value to server (servlet) and add the values to new table without refresh entire page.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "ur_servlet_url" + selRadio,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    success : function(data) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Let me know if this helps.